# Jest, Puppeteer, Typescript, ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm developing a Typescript library and am trying to write tests with Jest and Puppeteer.  The tests are failing because `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`.  I followed the Getting Started sections for both Jest and Jest-Puppeteer, but am still running into this issue.  How can Blob not be defined if the tests are running in the browser?  And what can I do to fix this?

```js
# jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    },
};
```

```js
# mylibrary.ts
function doSomething() {
  const blob = new Blob(...);
  return blob;
}
```

```js
# mylibrary.spec.ts
it('should return a blob', function(){
    const b = doSomething();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`jest-puppeteer`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer) allows you to use `puppeteer`. It will not automatically wrap your code (which should be running inside a browser) into a browser.

**Code Sample**

Here is an example how `jest-puppeteer` is supposed to be used:

```js
it('...', async () => {
    await page.goto('...');
});
```

**Problem Fix**

If you want to test a whole website inside a browser, go with `jest-puppeteer`. Then you will need to launch a local server and use puppeteer to visit your website.

If you want to run a client-side library on the server, you might want to use polyfills. You can use [`blob-polyfill`](https://github.com/bjornstar/blob-polyfill) in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to change testEnvironment from node to jsdom in my jest.config.json. My tests were I think default testEnvironment was jsdom but after using ts-jest it changed to node, so I changed it back to jsdom like this

Before

```
 module.exports = {
   preset: 'ts-jest',
   testEnvironment: 'node',
 };
```

after

```
 module.exports = {
   preset: 'ts-jest',
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
 }
```

Comment: What if i need the test to run in node env?

Comment: if you need Blob and you are running in the node environment, you may need some sort of polyfill. I guess i'd ask, are you sure you need blob under node (it is a browser API, so running it under node would be somewhat unusual) but if the answer is yes, then consider a polyfill probably.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative I found is to use a "setup file" in the jest configuration file as below:

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    // ...
    setupFiles: ['./src/setupTests.js']
};
```

`setupTests.js`:

```js
global.Blob = () => {};
```

My test has compiled, this setup only bypass compilation error.

If you want to mock further you must adapt the `setupTests.js` `global.Blob` assignment by your mocked class.